# reset old clicked element rel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one question about reset old clicked element rel. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/aNPJVW)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there are 5 number of button. Like the following html codes:

```
 <div class="item" id="a1" data-id="1" rel="a">1</div>
 <div class="item" id="b1" data-id="1" rel="b">2</div>
 <div class="item" id="c1" data-id="1" rel="c">3</div>
 <div class="item" id="d1" data-id="1" rel="d">4</div>
 <div class="item" id="e1" data-id="1" rel="e">5</div>
```

When you click button 1 then this button `rel="a"` will changing `rel="na"` you can see it in your developer console. Also same think for other buttons `(2,3,4,5)` .

Now what I need here. If you click `button 2` (after clicking `button 1`) I want to change previously clicked `rel="na"` to `rel="a"` and change the new clicked button 2 `rel="b"` to `rel="nb"`

For example:

first click button number 1

```
<div class="item" id="a1" data-id="1" rel="a">1</div>
```

and this `button 1` rel is `rel="na"` :

```
<div class="item" id="a1" data-id="1" rel="na">1</div>
```

after that click button number 2

```
<div class="item" id="b1" data-id="1" rel="b">2</div>
```

and this `button 2` rel is `rel="nb"` like

```
<div class="item" id="b1" data-id="1" rel="b">2</div>
```

at the same time the old clicked `button 1` rel need reset like

```
<div class="item" id="a1" data-id="1" rel="na">1</div>
```

to

```
<div class="item" id="a1" data-id="1" rel="a">1</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".item", function(){
      var dataid = $(this).attr("data-id");
      var REL = $(this).attr("rel");

      // Change Rel
      if (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].indexOf(REL) !== -1) {

         $('#' + REL + dataid).attr('rel', 'n' + REL);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Is attribute `rel` on DIV even valid?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I don't think it is, only on elements with a href, but some people seem to use `rel` on just about everything, instead of using valid data-attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the old `rel` value in jQuery's `data()`, and restore it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
        var dataid = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var rel    = $(this).attr("data-rel");
        var others = $(this).closest('.buttons').find('.item').not(this);

        $(this).data('_rel', rel);

        if (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].indexOf(rel) !== -1) {
            $('#' + rel + dataid).attr('data-rel', 'n' + rel);
        }

        others.attr('data-rel', function(_, rel) {
            return $(this).data('_rel') || rel;
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
   margin:0px auto;
   width:100%;
   max-width:550px;
   padding:5px;
   background-color:#d8dbdf;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   margin-top:50px;
   border-radius:2px;
   -webkit-border-radius:2px;
}

.buttons {
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}

.item {
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
   margin-right:5px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
.item:nth-child(2n+1){
   background-color:red;
   color:#ffffff;
   border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

   <div class="buttons">
      <div class="item" id="a1" data-id="1" data-rel="a">1</div>
      <div class="item" id="b1" data-id="1" data-rel="b">2</div>
      <div class="item" id="c1" data-id="1" data-rel="c">3</div>
      <div class="item" id="d1" data-id="1" data-rel="d">4</div>
      <div class="item" id="e1" data-id="1" data-rel="e">5</div>
   </div>

</div>



<div class="container">

   <div class="buttons">
      <div class="item" id="a2" data-id="2" data-rel="a">1</div>
      <div class="item" id="b2" data-id="2" data-rel="b">2</div>
      <div class="item" id="c2" data-id="2" data-rel="c">3</div>
      <div class="item" id="d2" data-id="2" data-rel="d">4</div>
      <div class="item" id="e2" data-id="2" data-rel="e">5</div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please check this demo. That is not working with multiple Please Check this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/aNPJVW) . I mean if i click other data-id="2" it is changing also old rel="x"

Comment: You didn't mention groups of elements with the same class

Comment: sorry for that dear. I forget to add it.

Comment: @DevStud Again... you *should not* use `rel` at all but rather `data-rel` if you will.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you for the warning.

Comment: I agree with @RokoC.Buljan, and have updated the answer to use valid data-attributes instead, and work with multiple instances.

Comment: Yes @adeneo i saw it. Thank you for your answer. That is solved my problem.

Comment: @adeneo Hi dear, if you have a time can you check my question for answer  ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314371/jquery-ajax-random-append-html-page-in-a-div-after-scroll